# Get output of command in if statement, into a variable

Tags: bash, ansible

I need entries in a Ansible hostfile, to be formatted in a way so it can be used in a normal host file on Linux. I am able to achieve that, by calling nslookup twice in my script.

The goal i to only call nslookup once, but i dont know how to get nslookup output in the if statement, into a variable.

I have tried this

```
if [[ $(nslookup $i > $DNSHOST) && $? == 0 ]]
if [[ $(nslookup $i > $DNSHOST && $? == 0) ]]
if  (($(nslookup $i > $DNSHOST) && $? == 0))
if [[ $("nslookup $i > $DNSHOST") && $? == 0 ]]
```

...and a lot of other combinations, but nothing works??

This script work and does the job:

```
for i in $HOSTS; do

                if [[ $(nslookup $i) && $? == 0 ]]; then

                        nslookup $i | sed -e '1,3d;6d' | cut -d$'\t' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | xargs -n2 | awk '{print $2,"\t",$1}'

                fi
done
```

This is the one i cant get to work:

```
for i in $HOSTS; do

        if [[ $(nslookup $i > $DNSHOST) && $? == 0 ]]; then

                cat $DNSHOST | sed -e '1,3d;6d' | cut -d$'\t' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | xargs -n2 | awk '{print $2,"\t\t",$1}'

        fi
done
```

When i use double quotes, i get the error 'directory does not exist'.
Else it just loops thorugh the host list, without nslookup.

Comment: Note that, in bash within `[[ double brackets ]]`, the `==` operator is not numeric equality, it is a *pattern matching* operator. At an interactive prompt, type `help [[`

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure, what you want.

But this looks curious:

```
if [[ $(nslookup $i > $DNSHOST) && $? == 0 ]]
```

Try instead:

```
if nslookup $i > $DNSHOST
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the nslookup output, you can still do that in the condition part of the if command:

```
if output=$( nslookup ... ); then 
    # do something with "$output"
fi
```

---

The problems with `if [[ $(nslookup $i > $DNSHOST) && $? == 0 ]]`

- you have 2 expressions: `$(nslookup $i > $dnshost)` and `$? == 0`
- `&&` short-circuits, so if the first expression evaluates to false, the boolean result cannot be true and the 2nd expression is not considered.
- The first expression:

  - since there is only one operand, true/false is determined by the *string length* of the operand
  - as you redirect the output into a file, the standard output result of the command substitution will be the empty string.
  - the empty string as an expression is false.

Note that the condition of the `if` command does not *have* to be in square brackets. If you want to write an if command to act on the *exit status* of some command, then you just write
`if some_command; then ...; else ...; fi`

At an interactive prompt: `help if`, `help [[`, `help test`